# using std::map<int , std::string> with Google Protocol Buffer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, protocol-buffers

I wanted to know if it was possible to use a map with a google protocol buffer.
I currently have something like this in my .proto file

```
message MsgA
{
required string symbol = 1 ;
optional int32  freq = 2   [default = 0]; 
}

message MsgB
{

   //What should I do to make a map<int,MsgA>
}
```

My question is in MsgB i would like to create a type that would be a map:: 
Any suggestion on how I could accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
message MapEntry
{
    required int32 mapKey  = 1;
    required MsgA mapValue = 2;
}

message MsgB
{
    repeated MapEntry = 1;
}
```

You will have to write your own code to convert the map to and from a MsgB, but that should be basically trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am thinking about replacing the map with a vector. For this I will use the repeated field. Which I believe would act like a vector. Could you tell me how I can add items to a repeated field in C++

Comment: @MistyD: Use `MapEntry& newMapEntry = myMsgB.add_mapentry();`. Then fill out the fields in `newMapEntry`, which is now a reference to a newly-added map entry in message b.

Comment: I was looking at that in https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial. Isnt it suppose to be `MapEntry* newMapEntry = myMsgB.add_mapentry();` ? A pointer instead of a reference ?

Comment: Since it using reference i wanted to know how we reclaim the memory and when is it safe to delete the pointer ?

Comment: Sorry, you can do it that way. I meant `MapEntry& newMapEntry = *myMsgB.add_mapentry();`.

Comment: @MistyD You never delete the pointer -- that would delete the message you just assembled.